# Keys and Dictionaries

Tags: python

it seems that my code isn't working well, everytime i run it it seems that the key value of agenda is replaced by the next one I enter instead of adding it as a new one. Please help my find why is this happening and how to i fix it. Thanks!

```
def contactos():
    q=int(raw_input("Desea agregar un contacto (1=si, 0=no): "))
    while q==1:

        a=raw_input("ingrese nombre contacto, telefono, mail (delimitados por espacio)")
        d=a.split()           

        agenda={}

        agenda[d[0]]= "nombre", d[0], "telefono: ", d[1], "mail :", d[2]

        q=int(raw_input("Desea agregar otro contacto (1=si, 0=no): "))

        print agenda.keys()


    return agenda
```

Comment: fyi, it's a good idea to keep all your code in english. also, follow PEP8 when formatting your code!

Comment: `agenda={}` resets the variable each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting `agenda` to an empty dictionary each time through the loop. Initialize it *once* before the loop.

```
def contactos():
    agenda = {}
    q=int(raw_input("Desea agregar un contacto (1=si, 0=no): "))
    while q==1:

        a=raw_input("ingrese nombre contacto, telefono, mail (delimitados por espacio)")
        d=a.split()           

        agenda[d[0]]= "nombre", d[0], "telefono: ", d[1], "mail :", d[2]

        q=int(raw_input("Desea agregar otro contacto (1=si, 0=no): "))

        print agenda.keys()
```

Do note Cyber's answer, as well, if you want to add multiple phone numbers and addresses for the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning, which will overwrite the value

```
agenda[d[0]]= "nombre", d[0], "telefono: ", d[1], "mail :", d[2]
```

You would have to `append`

```
agenda[d[0]].append(["nombre", d[0], "telefono: ", d[1], "mail :", d[2]])
```

Comment: That would require him to initialize the list first (e.g. using `setdefault`) or use a `defaultdict`

Comment: well, that didn't work... I didn't know you could use append function in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

you should/could use class instead

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

here is a very simple example

```
class contact:
    def __init__(self, name="", phone="", mail=""):
        self.phone = phone
        self.name = name
        self.mail = mail




a = contact("A name")
print a.name
a.mail = "test@gmail.com"
print a.mail
```